# Inputing Snippet in div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, expressionengine, code-snippets

I have a snippet {example} - i would like to add that snippet through a jquery function like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
var value = $('#formname').attr("value");
if (value == "workspace-brochure") { 
      $('#results').text("{sn-english-workspace-thanks}");
    }
});//]]>  
</script>
```

it doesnt seem to be working though. anyone familiar with jquery and expression engine that can let me know if this is even possible.

Comment: What is `#formname`? Should you be using `.val()` instead of `.attr("value")`?

Comment: #formname is a input field of a form and thats the ID. the function works with just inputting a regular string, but not with the snippet, i am assuming probably because of the "{"

Comment: btw.. yes i guess i should be using .val()

Comment: It appears you are trying to get a value from the form itself, btu a form has no values, only the inputs within the form. and as Eric said you should be using .val() to get the value

Comment: I have tried with you code in my asp.net and it works fine. I am using '#formname" as input type checkbox and '#results' as div. By the way if possible please give all code with html. Before that also please check with any spell mistake with control id.

Comment: mit...did you try it with a snippet in this form {sn-example}  instead of just a regular string

Comment: Daniel, yes I am trying to get an input in the form, but just putting $('#results').text("text here"); works fine.. so i assume the problem is with the value that i put in .text()  .. ill try .val() though

Comment: btw #formname IS the id for the input

Comment: Keep in mind you'll need this JS to be embedded in the template file (not in a separate JS script) in order for this to work as ExpressionEngine needs to process the template and replace any vars before outputting. Can you confirm 100% that the conditional is being met (with a console.log or something?).

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in my testing:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="formname" value="workspace-brochure">
</form>
<div id="results"></div>

<script>
$(function () {
    var value = $('#formname').val();
    if (value == "workspace-brochure") {
        $('#results').text("{sn-english-workspace-thanks}");
    }
});
</script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phripley/rE2G7/